# How to disable Color filters hotkey

Tags: windows, hotkeys

I'm using windows in Parallels and keep accidentally turning on the color filter in windows turning the screen black and white.  The Hot key is <kbd>win</kbd> + <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd>.  So it is very close to Mac/Windows copy command.

It's a useless feature for me, so how can I disable this hot key?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways to do this.

### 1. Run a recent version of Windows

(As of Feb 2018, this is available in developer preview 17083 and later).

It's literally a checkbox in the **Settings-->Ease of Access** pane:

[image]

### 2. Edit the registry

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\ColorFiltering

HotkeyEnabled DWORD

0 = Disable
1 = Enable
```

If you can wait to disable this until it's rolled out to everyone, you probably don't want to go hacking on the Windows registry. My advice is to be patient until the feature rolls out in a gold release. Hopefully Microsoft will have the wisdom to disable this feature by default.

Source: https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/103066-enable-disable-color-filters-hotkey-windows-10-a.html

Comment: Awesome! Thanks.

Comment: Looks like the new version of Parallels fixes this as well.